# How to tee into fd's instead of named pipes

Tags: bash, pipe

I want to take stdout of a process and analyze it with three different programs.  I have been able to use named pipes, but can I use fd's instead.

Here's what works so far:

```
exec 3< <(myprog)
tee p1 p2 >/dev/null <&3

cat p1|ap1 &
cat p2|ap2 &
```

p1 and p2 were created with mkfifo.  ap1 and ap2 are analysis programs.  I don't know if I'm saying this right, but is there a way to `tee` into two new fd's instead?  Something like this:

```
exec 3< <(myprog)
tee >&4 >&5 <&3

cat <&4|ap1 &
cat <&5|ap2 &
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You almost had it:

```
myprog | tee >(ap1) >(ap2) >(ap3) >/dev/null
```

Note that `ap1` can be a function. If you want the function to have access to your script's argument, call it with `"$@"`, i.e.,

```
ap1 () {
  # here the script arguments are available as $1, $2, ...
}
# ditto for ap2, ap3
myprog | tee >(ap1 "$@") >(ap2 "$@") >(ap3 "$@") >/dev/null
```

If your shell doesn't support `>()` (bash, ksh and zsh do, but it's not POSIX), but your OS nonetheless supports `/dev/fd` (most unices do, including Solaris, Linux, *BSD, OSX and Cygwin), you can use explicit fd shuffling.

```
{ { { myprog | tee /dev/fd/3 /dev/fd/4 |
      ap1 >&2
    } 3>&1 |
    ap2 >&2
  } 4>&1 |
  ap3 >&2
}
```

Comment: Ahh.  That may work.  Is there a way to tee to fd's though?  ap1 and ap2 are huge commands with pipelines and tons of switches.  It will be easier to read if I can use an fd.

Comment: @User1: it's definitely possible (and has the advantage of working in shells that don't support `<()` and `>()`), but the syntax is awkward. Here it would be simpler to define `ap1` and `ap2` as functions.

Comment: What is the other syntax?  I just noticed that I use if statements in some parts of the script that modify how ap1 is called according to input parameters.  `>()` probably won't work too well in my case.  But I don't know how else I can call it.  Any ideas?  Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @User1: You can easily pass the parameters to the function, see my edit. And here's how to do it without `>()`; but you'd to it for the portability, not for the readability! I insist, functions are the way to go in your case.